# Collection.find() for array inside object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I have a Meteor app that has a collection of chat groups. Each document in this collection looks like this:

`{groupname: 'name', whitelist: ['person1', 'person2', 'person3'], messages:['message1', 'message2', 'message3']}`

To show each person with an account what groups they are part of, I need a page with a list of those groups they're allowed in. How can I use a find() command to return all of the documents whose whitelist array contains the user's name?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ChatGroups.find({whitelist: Meteor.user().username});
```

This assumes that `username` is the property you want to match against. You don't need to do anything special to search within an array in this case - mongo will do the correct thing (compare `username` to each element of each `whitelist` and return those documents that match).

Comment: Does the object have to be a embedded document or can it still be an array?

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not really sure what you mean. I think just reading the docs for [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) would be useful - it covers a lot of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

To search in MongoDB by array items - use `$in` operator:

```
ChatGroups.find({
   whitelist: {
      $in: [Meteor.user()._id]
   }
});
```

Reference: [Comparison Query Operators > $in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)